# Cannot Read UART data

Tags: c, uart, nxp-microcontroller

What I'm trying to do is simple enough, read ASCII data from UART. I'm using an NXP [kl27](https://www.nxp.com/products/processors-and-microcontrollers/arm-based-processors-and-mcus/kinetis-cortex-m-mcus/l-seriesultra-low-powerm0-plus/kinetis-kl2x-48-mhz-usb-ultra-low-power-microcontrollers-mcus-based-on-arm-cortex-m0-plus-core:KL2x) and am using Kinetis 1.2.0. I have a GPS (tx pin) wired to pin PTD2, and have that pin configured to be UART2_Rx.

```
PORT_HAL_SetMuxMode(PORTD,2u,kPortMuxAlt3); //UART2_Rx
PORT_HAL_SetMuxMode(PORTE,22u,kPortMuxAlt4); //UART2_Tx (unused)
```

The configuration for the UART object is as follows:

```
uart_user_config_t g_uartConfig= {
    .baudRate = 9600u,
    .parityMode = kUartParityDisabled,
    .stopBitCount = kUartOneStopBit,
    .bitCountPerChar = kUart8BitsPerChar,
};
```

Finally, here is the code I'm using to try and recieive UART data:

```
uart_state_t g_uartState;
UART_DRV_Init(2u, &g_uartState, &g_uartConfig);

uint8_t rxChar
// Uart #, return data, data count, timeout in miliseconds
UART_DRV_ReceiveDataBlocking(2u, &rxChar, 1u,1000u);
```

The problem is UART_DRV_RecieveDataBlocking never returns.

Here is the relevant parts of the schematic if that helps:
[image: diagram]

## What I've Tried

1. I have confirmed that the GPS is outputting data
2. I have confirmed that pin PTD2 is in fact connected and receiving data (thanks to an oscilloscope)
3. Sending UART data with pin PTE22 to see if the fault lied with the UART object. The data sent successfully.
4. Debugging with GDB. This quickly turned into a rabbit hole and I just gave up after a while. What I did find out is that the code waits forever in the debugger after calling UART_SET_C3 in fsl_uart_hal.c ([line 325](https://github.com/ErichStyger/mcuoneclipse/blob/master/Examples/KDS/TWR-KV58F220M/TWR-KV58F220M/SDK/platform/hal/src/uart/fsl_uart_hal.c))
5. Altering the config object (changing parityMode).

Far as I can tell I'm following every example/demo I've seen with reading UART data. If anyone has any ideas about what is going on I'd love to hear it.

Comment: where is the code for the UART_DRV_* functions?

Comment: when examining the data from the GPS chip..1) what was the baud rate 2)how many stop bits?  3) was a parity bit being sent?  4) was the TX line being held 'low' between characters? 5( what was the inter-character time?  6) what was the bit time?  7) What was the 'high' voltage level (compared to ground)?  8) What was the 'low' voltage level (compared to ground).  9) what was the VCC voltage level (compared to gnd)?  did the 3D-FIX line ever go 'high'?

Comment: "Cannot Read UART data" --> Should something be connected to the RX pin?  "pin PTD2 is in fact connected and receiving data" ==> that is connected to the TX pin??  This does not look consistent with the `PORT_HAL_SetMuxMode()` calls.

Comment: @user3629249 the UART code is part of the SDK. Specifically in fsl_uart_driver.c

Comment: As for the bulk of your questions I'll have to get the scope back out tomorrow to find out. From what I remember though the baud is 9600, and the 3d fx pin has gone low when it gets a lock. Parity is disabled I believe.

Comment: @chux  The Rx pin on the GPS itself is not connect as I have no plans to use it. PTD2 is UART2_Rx which is connected to the Tx pin on the GPS. According to the MCU's data sheet, alt3 is uart2_rx on PTD2. Which part looks inconsistent?

Comment: @user3629249 Here is what I've been able to find.  baud is 9600, 1 stop bit, no parity. Tx appears high between characters. High voltage is about 1.5 volts. Low is 0. VCC is 3 volts. As stated 3d fx goes low when it gets a fix. Not sure how to answer the rest.

Comment: is 1.5volts high enough for the cpu board your using to be positively recognized as a 'high'

Comment: OK, I thought the code was for the part shown.

Comment: @user3629249 Tried bypassing the resistor on the GPS Tx. MCU still didn't recognize the signal. I'm pretty sure my problem is something with the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was indeed software. My cmakeLists file was missing this:

```
"${ProjDirPath}/KSDK_1.2.0/platform/drivers/src/uart/fsl_uart_irq.c"
```

This file properly sets up the UART interrupts.